# Meaning of "smooth finite-rank operators $Q$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$"

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

What does it mean for a finite-rank operator to be "smooth"? How can one finite-rank operator be smoother than another? For me, a finite-rank operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ has an expression
$$Q=\sum_{j=1}^N\langle \phi_j,\cdot\rangle\psi_j$$ for $(\phi_j)_{j=1}^N$ and $(\psi_j)_{j=1}^N$ orthonormal.

So a guess is saying that $(\psi_j)$ have to be smooth as well as in $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?

Comment: I agree, the concept of smoothness does not apply to abstract Hilbert space vectors so it most likely refers to the fact that $\psi_j\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ is also in [$C^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)

Comment: Could you indicate where you found such a terminology?